Characterize descents of geometric finite étale cover by means of homotopy exact sequence
Let $X/k$ be a geometrically connected $k$-variety (=separated of finite type, esp quasi-compact; the base field $k$ assumed to be separable, so $\overline{k}=k^{\text{sep}}$), $\overline{X} := X \otimes_k \operatorname{Spec}(\overline{k})$ and $x: \operatorname{Spec}(\overline{k}) \to \overline{X}$ a geometric point of $\overline{X}$ and $x'$ the image of $x$.
Then there is well know homotopy exact sequence
$$ 1 \to \pi_1(\overline{X},x) \to \pi_1(X,x') \to \operatorname{Gal}(k) \to 1. $$
Let $f:Y \to \overline{X}$ a finite etale covering (FET) of $\overline{X}$, in terms of correspondence a finite set (=$f^{-1}(x))$ together with continuous $\pi_1(\overline{X},x)$-action.
The descents of $f$ a FET's $f': Y \to X$ whose base change along canonical projection $\overline{X} \to X$ is isomorphic as FET to $f$. In terms of actions that's sets whose $\pi_1(X,x)$-action precomposed with left map in the sequence (:=HES) above gives $\pi_1(\overline{X},x)$-action of $f$. (At least, that's how I understand it.)
Question: Is it possible to characterize all descents of $f$ in terms of the above HES?
More concretely my question is motivated by following special situation from here:
Assume that $x'$ has as its image in $X$ a $k$-rational point which we call also $x'$ and $f:Y \to \overline{X}$ as above a FET.
How to see that there exist a unique descent $f'_r$ of $f$ which has a $k$-rational point in its fibre over $x'$. Especially, why it is unique? Can it be elaborated in detail? (my sources are Szamuely, Chap 5 & SGA1, Exposé IX, Chap 6 which seemingly do not adress this issue explicitly. Maye behind the lines, but I not see it)
Progress: In comments below the previously linked question Will Chen explains that one can describe the descents of $f$ in terms of covers restricted to $x'$ and that there should be one unique descent whose fibre over $x'$ contains a $k$-rational point.
Could it be elaborated how to see it? Naïvely, a cover of $X$ whose fibre over $x'$ contains rational points means just that its restriction to $x'$ admits sections. But it's not equivalent to that the restriction to $x'$ is trivial. Or do I have actually wrong picture in mind?
So my question is to elaborate why as stated by Will Chen the descents of $f$ correspond to covers restricted to $x'$ and why the descent whose fibre over $x'$ contains a $k$-rational point corresponds to trivial cover of $x'$, and why it's unique with this property?

You reference SGA I, X, but that may be a typo; @WillChen references SGA1, Exposé IX.

I don't claim that "exists rational point" = "trivial cover" in general. But I believe it is true in the situation of your linked question.

@WillChen: sorry, if I misquoted you. Indeed, over point space $\text{Spec}(k)$ this is actually only an "=" if the cover is additionally Galois, but yes, in general clearly only  direction "<=" is trivially true. What I mean (...and probably misunderstood) is the part where you wrote in the other thread: "The descent which admits a rational point is the one whose restriction is a trivial cover of $o_{E_k}$. This suggests that you assume implicitly that these descents are Galois, or not?

@WillChen: Previously you posted so far I remember correctly an answer using cohomological approach which you have later deleted. Did it contained some gaps? Unfortunately I didn't managed to read it in detail up to now and would appreciate to study it. Could you post it again (...even if it contained potential gaps or not covers completely all issues this question asked for; I'm pretty sure it was very interesting from didactical reasons)?

In general, if there exists a $k$-descent $\xi_0$ of some object $\xi$ over $\overline{k}$, then another $k$-descent is also called a ``twist'' of $\xi_0$. You should then expect the set of twists to be related to $H^1(k,\text{Aut}(\xi))$, where the automorphism group is suitably interpreted. For example, the situation for twists of curves is described in Silverman's Arithmetic of elliptic curves, chapter X.2.
Returning to the situation at hand, a degree $n$ finite etale cover of $\overline{X}$ corresponds to a homomorphism $\overline{\rho} : \pi_1(\overline{X})\rightarrow S_n$, up to conjugation in $S_n$. Its descents to $X$, if they exist, correspond to ways of extending $\overline{\rho}$ to a representation $\rho : \pi_1(X)\rightarrow S_n$, where $\pi_1(\overline{X})$ is embedded inside $\pi_1(X)$ via the base change map $\overline{X}\rightarrow X$.
If we assume that that there exists a descent $f_0$ of your cover $f : Y\rightarrow\overline{X}$, then there is a natural action of $\text{Gal}(k)$ on $\text{Aut}(f)$, and the set of descents should be in bijection with the group cohomology $H^1(\text{Gal}(k),\text{Aut}(f))$, where $\text{Aut}(f)$ is the group of deck transformations of the cover $f$, with the given $\text{Gal}(k)$-action.
I expect the bijection should be given as follows. Let $f_0'$ be another descent of $f$. Then $\overline{f_0'} := f_0'\times_k \overline{k}$ is isomorphic, over $\overline{k}$, to $\overline{f_0} = f$. If $\phi : \overline{f_0'}\rightarrow f$ is an isomorphism (over $k'$), then for any $\sigma\in\text{Gal}(k)$, $\phi^\sigma\circ\phi^{-1}\in\text{Aut}(f)$, and this defines a 1-cocycle $\text{Gal}(k)\rightarrow\text{Aut}(f)$ relative to the above mentioned action of $\text{Gal}(k)$ on $\text{Aut}(f)$. A different choice of isomorphism $\phi$ will give rise to a different cocycle, but the two cocycles give the same class in $H^1(\text{Gal}(k),\text{Aut}(f))$. This should yield a bijection between $H^1(\text{Gal}(k),\text{Aut}(f))$ with the set of descents of $f$.
If the homotopy exact sequence for $\pi_1(X)$ is split -- i.e., $\pi_1(X)\cong\pi_1(\overline{X})\rtimes \text{Gal}(k)$ (e.g., if $X$ admits a $k$-rational point, or $\text{Gal}(k)$ is a projective profinite group, e.g. if $k$ is finite), then we can check this explicitly as follows:
First note that a map $G\rtimes H\rightarrow S_n$ is the same as giving maps $\varphi : G\rightarrow S_n$ and $\psi : H\rightarrow S_n$ such that
$$\varphi(h.g) = \psi(h)\varphi(g)\psi(h)^{-1} \text{ for all $g\in G, h\in H$}. \qquad\qquad(*)$$
Equivalently, if $\alpha : H\rightarrow\text{Aut}(G)$ is the action homomorphism, this says that $\varphi\circ \alpha(h) = \text{inn}(\psi(h))\circ\varphi$ for all $h\in H$. If $\psi' : H\rightarrow S_n$ is another map satisfying this property, then we must have $\text{inn}(\psi'(h)^{-1}\psi(h))\circ\varphi = \varphi$, which is to say $\psi'(h)^{-1}\psi(h)\in C_{S_n}(\text{Im}(\varphi))$. The map $h\mapsto \psi'(h)^{-1}\psi(h)$ is a 1-cocycle $\delta : H\rightarrow C_{S_n}(\text{Im}(\varphi))$, where $h\in H$ acts on $C_{S_n}(\text{Im}(\varphi))$ by conjugation by $\psi(h)$. Note that $\psi(h)$ normalizes $\text{Im}(\varphi)$, and hence also normalizes $C_{S_n}(\text{Im}(\varphi))$, so this makes sense.
In other words, if we take $G = \pi_1(\overline{X})$ and $H = \text{Gal}(k)$, then the set of all descents/twists of $f$ (i.e., extensions of of $\varphi$) are represented by $(\varphi,\delta\psi)$, where $\psi$ is a fixed map satisfying $(*)$ above, and $\delta$ is a 1-cocycle $H\rightarrow C_{S_n}(\text{Im}(\varphi))$.
One should then check that two pairs $(\varphi,\delta\psi)$, $(\varphi,\delta'\psi)$ are conjugate (in $S_n$) if and only if $\delta,\delta,$ represent the same class in $H^1(\text{Gal}(k),C_{S_n}(\text{Im}(\varphi)))$, or in other words, the descents are in bijection with $H^1(\text{Gal}(k),C_{S_n}(\text{Im}(\varphi)))$. I am too lazy to check this carefully but I'm sure it's true (write a comment if it's not!). Noting that $\text{Aut}(f)\cong C_{S_n}(\text{Im}(\varphi))$, we find that this description is compatible with the geometric description given earlier.
In the special case that $\alpha$ is the trivial action, there exists a descent where the homomorphism $\psi$ is zero (and hence $\text{Aut}(f)$ has trivial $\text{Gal}(k)$-action). If moreover $f$ is Galois (i.e. $\varphi$ is the left regular representation), then since the centralizer of the left regular representation is the right regular representation, $\psi(H)$ acts by right multiplication on the Galois group, which can be identified with the image of $\varphi$, and hence every nontrivial $\psi$ will have no fixed points (i.e., $\psi = 0$ is the unique twist which has a fixed point). If moreover the splitting of the homotopy exact sequence comes from a rational point $x$, then this shows that there is a unique descent of $f$ which admits a rational point lying above $x$, and that this descent is totally split above $x$.

...I assume in spirit of usual philosophy to encode certain (iso classes of) geometr objects in terms of certain cohomological classes that there should be also exist an "obstruction" space ( guess, certain H^2 - but not sure if the Galois module would be still Aut(f) ) determining if a geometric cover admits a descent...

By the way, where you wrote "[...] where the automorphism group is suitably interpreted". So far I know over fields, etale and Galois coho coinside, so cannot we be precise there by saying that the Aut group is interpreted as Galois module, not more not less? Or is there more subtleties with "interpretation of Aut" involved?

...also, your $k'$ in 4th paragraph is actually $\overline{k}$,right?

There are another points about which I'm still not sure: You remarked in last paragraph that "if $f$ Galois - i.e. $\varphi$
is a regular representation- , then $\psi(H)$ acts by multiplication on the image of $\varphi$" Firstly, what do you mean by a regular rep? Isn't there "a" unique regular rep, but I'm not sure if you meant this one $\varphi$ as you constructed it not as acting on itself, as $G$ is infinite, $S_n$ not, but FET's correspond to actions

on finite sets. Doen't Galois cover here translates in this context to that the action by $\varphi$ is free & transitive?

Moreover I not understand why in this case $\psi(H)$
acts by multiplication. Is't this given in the way you constructed it intrinsically by conjugation and not a multiplication?

@user267839 By "suitably interpreted", I just mean that you have to view the object inside the right category. For a finite etale map $f : X\rightarrow Y$, 99% of the time people will understand an automorphism to be an automorphism of $X$ inducing the identity on $Y$, but 1% of the time someone might wonder if you mean an automorphism of $X$ which descends to a (possibly nonidentity) automorphism of $Y$.

I see; also as little update I think that my questions from prev comments have all been resolved now. The only point that I still not got is why there is iso $\text{Aut}(f)\cong C_{S_n}(\text{Im}(\varphi))$? From your argumentation on encoding descents as extensions in terms of $1$-cycles we can deduce that there is 1 to 1 corresp between $1$-cocycles $H \to \text{Aut}(f)$ and $H \to  C_{S_n}(\text{Im}(\varphi))$ - so their $H^1$ coho coinside. But this not neccessary imply that there Galois modules are isomorphic. Could you elaborate the reason why this still the case?

@user267839 By the Galois correspondence, $f$ corresponds to the set ${1,2,\ldots,n}$, together with the action of $G$ given by $\varphi$. The automorphisms of $f$ correspond to automorphisms of this $G$-set, which is exactly $C_{S_n}(\text{Im}(\varphi))$.
